# VBA Editor complaining about a missing object

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason VBE tells that ConcatenateRows needs an object, I am not quite sure why, Immediate window tells me that `ConsolidateRange` is a Range:

```
Option Explicit
Private ConsolidateRange As Range

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    RangeConsiolidateForm.Show
End Sub


Private Sub RangeInput_Change()
    Set ConsolidateRange = Range(RangeInput)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Direction.AddItem "Rows"
    Direction.AddItem "Columns"
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    If Direction = "Rows" Then
        ConcatenateRows (ConsolidateRange)
        RangeConsiolidateForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Public Sub ConcatenateRows(InputRange as range)
....bunch of code....
End Sub
```

Update: The error I am gettign is "Run-Time error '424': Object required"

Comment: questions: 1) what line is throwing the error?  2) in the `RangeInput_Change` procedure, where is the RangeInput variable being defined and set, and what is it defined as and set to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your call

`ConcatenateRows (ConsolidateRange)`

to

`ConcatenateRows ConsolidateRange`

This is an old VBA catch on procedure calls for newbies.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I hate this syntax :(

Comment: The syntax is here due to historical reasons. You can spot the problem by different auto-formatting of parentheses. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @sgp667 embrace it. What you've been doing with the braces, is forcing everything to be passed by value.

Comment: absolutelly it is, stackoveflow prevents me from marking it as correct for another 5min

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes, *making a copy*, as in passing `ByVal` even though the signature implicitly or explicitly says `ByRef` - in other words, using braces all the time without knowing what it does, not only creates confusion but can introduce subtle bugs. Embrace the standard  implicit procedure call syntax (`DoSomething 42`), or use the ugly and obsolete and otherwise utterly useless `Call` statement if you really really really want those parens everywhere (`Call DoSomething(42)`).

Comment: You can also change the definition of your function from `Public Sub ConcatenateRows(InputRange as range)` to `Public Sub ConcatenateRows(ByRef InputRange as range)`

Comment: @ChipsLetten that will have no effect, parameters are passed `ByRef` by default in VBA.